# discord.py not detecting messages, i want it to detect specific word in messages but it doesnt work

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

discord.py not detecting messages

```
@client.event
async def on_messge(ctx):
    msg = ctx.content()
    words_list = ["check", 'for', 'any', 'word', 'from', 'list']

    if any(word in msg for word in words_list):
      await ctx.send("message here")
```

discord.py not detecting messages, i want it to detect specific word in messages but it doesnt work

my bot needs to detect the specific word in the message but it doesnt

where am i making the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the event is called [`on_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message), not `on_messge`, so your event handler will never get called. However, there's a lot more issues than that.

> ```py
> on_messge(ctx)
> ```

As the docs page will also tell you, the argument passed to `on_message` is a `discord.Message` instance, not a `Context` instance, so using it as a `Context` will never work.

> ```py
> msg = ctx.content()
> ```

`Context.content()` doesn't exist, as the [docs for `Context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context) will tell you, but luckily for you (as mentioned above) it's actually a `Message` and not a `Context` instance, so that won't be a problem in this case. However, [`content`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.Message.content) is an **attribute**, **not a method**, so you **can't call it**.

> ```py
> await ctx.send("message here")
> ```

Again, the argument is a `Message` instance, and `Message.send()` doesn't exist either as the [docs for `Message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.Message) will tell you. Either use [`Message.reply()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.Message.reply), or send a message to the channel instead.

All in all, make sure you read the docs for something before randomly using it and assuming it exists or that it will work.

Comment: im sick i can't focus i made a lot of mistakes thank you